# Overlay spectrogram with additional plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot spectrogram in Python and overlay it with an additional plot, e.g. dots indicating special areas of interest. This is what I was doing in the past:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.specgram(signal, NFFT=2**10, Fs=singal_rate)
plt.plot(x, y, 'go') # additional plot
plt.savefig('spectrogram.png')
```

Regardless of order of the plots, I will always get only the dot and not a spectrogram with the dot. Here's what I'd like to reproduce:

[image]

Spectrogram is overlayed with additional information. As you can see from [the code](https://github.com/tracek/Ornithokrites/blob/master/reporting.py#L81) it worked in the past. I am on Python 2.7.12, matplotlib 1.5.3.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem using Python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 1.5.1

Comment: Thanks for the info @Michael I did try Python 3 and worked just fine. Perhaps something fishy with my environment.